# finding problem in abstract class in opps topic

Tags: java, object, oop, abstract-class

I will make an abstract class of shape and write a method of find a area of circle,rectangle & square
but after proceeding the code my answer wa come for both rectangle and square but in circle it found an error.

below is code.

My abstract class `shape`

```java
abstract class shape {
    public void printName() {
        System.out.println("My name is Pranjal Sharma");
    }
    abstract public int Area();
}
```

Subclass `rectangle`

```java
class rectangle extends shape {
    int l;
    int b;
    @Override
    public int Area() {
        return l * b;
    }
}
```

Subclass `circle`

```java
class circle extends shape{
    int r;
    @Override
    public double Area() {
        return Math.PI*r*r;
    }
}
```

Subclass `square`

```java
class square extends shape{
    int side;
    @Override
    public int Area() {
        return side*side;
    }
}
```

My `main`.

```java
public class oops_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rectangle r = new rectangle();
        r.l = 4;
        r.b = 4;
        System.out.println(r.Area());
        square s=new square();
        s.side=4;
        System.out.println(s.Area());
        circle c=new circle();
        c.r=4;
        System.out.println(c.Area());
    }
}
```

My expectation was also code of circle was run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you try to return a `double` for `circle` in `Area()` but you have declared `Area()` to return an `int` in your abstract class.

There are two possible ways to fix this:

##### Round `double` value for `Area()` of `circle()` to `int`

You can do this similar to the following. This will make sure that the rounded value will actually fit into an `int`.

```java
int longCastToInt;
try {
   longCastToInt = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(my_int));
} catch (ArithmeticException e){
    System.err.println("Value is does not fit into an int value!");
}
```

This way is probably not the way you should go, as you will only get rounded results for `circle`.

###### Use `double` in abstract class `shape` and adjust subclasses accordingly

This is what you should probably do. Adjust the return type of `Area()` to `double` and do that for all subclasses accordingly and your code will run and print the correct results.

Abstract class `shape`

```java
abstract class shape {
    public void printName() {
        System.out.println("My name is Pranjal Sharma");
    }
    abstract public double Area();
}
```

Subclass `rectangle`

```java
class rectangle extends shape {
    int l;
    int b;
    @Override
    public double Area() {
        return l * b;
    }
}
```

Subclass `circle`

```java
class circle extends shape{
    int r;
    @Override
    public double Area() {
        return Math.PI*r*r;
    }
}
```

Subclass `square`

```java
class square extends shape{
    int side;
    @Override
    public double Area() {
        return side*side;
    }
}
```

My `main`.

```java
public class oops_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rectangle r = new rectangle();
        r.l = 4;
        r.b = 4;
        System.out.println(r.Area());
        square s=new square();
        s.side=4;
        System.out.println(s.Area());
        circle c=new circle();
        c.r=4;
        System.out.println(c.Area());
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
16.0
16.0
50.26548245743669
```

#### Another remark

You should follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), so start your class names with a capital letter (e.g. `circle` should be `Circle`) and start your methods with a lower case letter, so `Area()` should be `area()`.

Comment: Please consider marking this as an [*accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) if this worked for you :)